# Linear transformation and linear dependency

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that T: V -> V is a linear operator and {V1.....Vn} is linearly dependent. Show that {T(V1)...T(Vn)} is linearly dependent.

I tried this,
[My try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQdj7.jpg)

Anyone can help me.
Thank you

Comment: You are starting with the assumption that what you have to prove is true. Start with the assumption that $\{V_1,V_2,...,V_n\}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: after applying what @KaviRamaMurthy said, looks like you got this: T(ax+by)=aT(x)+bT(y)

Comment: You're asked to prove "If $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, then $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is", not the other way round. 

So you start by choosing a set of $c_i$ for which $\sum c_iv_i=0$, and show that $\sum c_i T(v_i)=0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\sum C_iv_i=0$ where $C_i$ are in the ground field not all zero. Now

$0=T(\sum C_iv_i)=\sum C_iT(v_i)$ with not all $C_i$ zero. This is equivalent to say that $\{T(v_1),...T(v_n)\}$ are linearly dependent.